# Create a storage pool on Windows Server 2012 with existing data?

Tags: windows-server-2012

I have an existing 2TB drive that's about 1/3 full.  I have another 2TB drive that I'd like to add and create a storage pool for redundancy.  The only problem is, I can only add the empty drive to a storage pool.  Is there any way to create a new storage pool while still preserving my existing data?

Thanks!
tim

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to create a storage pool with existing data. Storage pools are only a collection of drives that are managed by windows. You have to create one or more virtual disks from a storage pool. These virtual disks can be managed as if they are a regular hard drive(format, partitions, filesystem, ...). The data on the virtual disks is saved to the drives associated with the storage pool.

Easy solution:

- copy your data to an external hard drive
- create storage space with both hard drive
- create a virtual disk with mirror
- copy your data from the external drive to the virtual disk

complex solution if no additional hard drive is available:

- create a storage space with the free hard drive
- create a virtual disk(fixed size, simple) with the capacity of your data
- copy your data to the created virtual disk
- add the second hard drive to the storage pool
- create a mirror virtual drive with the remaining capacity of the storage pool
- copy the data from the simple virtual drive to the mirrored virtual drive
- delete the simple virtual drive
- extend the mirror virtual drive to 2 TB

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I was fortunate enough to borrow an external drive large enough to hold all my data so I did exactly what you said in your first solution!